# Netlogo: Syntax issue for setting neighbor values

Tags: netlogo

I'm using Netlogo and I'd like to set up a scenario whereby my turtles cannot move to the previous patch, nor can they move to the previous-previous patch (i.e. patches an individual turtle occupied at t-1 and at t-2).

I've set things up as shown below. The idea is to set neighbors that have already been visited by the current turtle to have a patch_attractiveness of zero, so they can't be selected. I think I'm just struggling with the correct syntax. The line at issue is the one that starts with "set previously_visited_patches"

```
patches-own [patch_attractiveness]

turtles-own [previous2_patches]

to setup 
  create-turtles 100  [
    set previous2_patches (list patch-here)
  ]
end

to go
  tick

  ask turtles [
    let previous_patchset patch-set previous2_patches
    let previously_visited_neighbors neighbors with [member? self previous_patchset]
    ask previously_visited_neighbours [
      set patch_attractiveness 0
    ]
    face max-one-of neighbors [patch_attractiveness]
    fd 1
  ]

  set previous2_patches lput patch-here previous2_patches
  if (ticks > 1) [
    set previous2_patches remove-item 0 previous2_patches 
  ]

end
```

The code as it stands seems to select the t-2 patch but not the t-1 patch as well. Anyone got any bright ideas? I'm assuming that "self" may not be the right call to make

Many thanks

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your logic. If you set the attractiveness to 0, then that patch will be unattractive to ALL turtles, not just the ones that have recently visited it. I don't think you need this anyway, you can just use the list (as you are doing) to track the last two patches and exclude them from the choices agentset. Do you want the turtle to be able to revisit after 3 ticks?

Comment: Good point. There is an error in my code listed above. My original actually has turtles-own [attractiveness] and then a line for each turtle that asks neighbors [set patch_attractiveness attractiveness]. This prevents changing the value for all patches. I would indeed like the turtles to be able to revisit after 3 ticks. But I've still not be able to find the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think this does what you want.

```
patches-own [patch-attractiveness]

turtles-own [previous2-patches]

to setup
  clear-all 
  create-turtles 100
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set previous2-patches (list patch-here patch-here)
  ]
  ask patches [ set patch-attractiveness random 50 ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles
  [ let candidates viable-neighbours neighbors previous2-patches
    if any? candidates
    [ face max-one-of candidates [patch-attractiveness]
      forward 1
      set previous2-patches (list patch-here item 0 previous2-patches)
    ]
  ]
end

to-report viable-neighbours [ set-of-patches delete-list ]
  let viable set-of-patches
  foreach delete-list
  [ x -> if member? x viable [ ask x [ set viable other viable ] ] ]
  report viable
end
```

First, I changed the variable names to hyphens instead of underscore. Sorry, hyphens is sort of conventional in NetLogo and I didn't realise you'd used underscores until I got errors.

I did some simplifying. I scrapped your stuff about setting attractiveness to 0 due to comments. I also simplified the setup so that the starting list of excluded patches is simply two copies of the current patch (which means you don't need the `if ticks > 1` test). I also created the new list from the current patch and the relevant item in the existing list - your lput and remove is more correct but since the list is only ever two items, this is easier to read. You should definitely retain the lput/remove structure if you may want to increase the memory of patches to exclude.

The important bit though is the new procedure. You pass it an agentset (in your case `neighbors`) and a list of agents to exclude (in your case the turtle variable previous2-patches) and it returns an agentset without the exclusions.It does this by running through the list and, if it's in the agentset, removing it with the `other` primitive.